# Don't undestand cause of this 'dict' object is not callable" error

Tags: python, loops, collections, containers

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to enter a sentence, then it counts and displays the occurrence of each letter.

I have to write a program using loops and collections/containers, which counts all the letters in a sentence input and displays how many times each was used. `'A'` and `'a'` count as the same letter.

This is my code so far:

```
def split(sentence): 
    return [char for char in sentence]
    
def get_key(val):
    for key, value in letters.items():
         if val == value:
             return key
    
letters = {'a': ['a','A'], 'b': ['b','B'], 'c': ['c','C'], 'd': ['d','D'], 'e': ['e','E'], 'f': ['f','F'], 'g': ['g','G'], 
    'h': ['h','H'], 'i': ['i','I'],'j': ['j','J'], 'k': ['k','K'], 'l': ['l','L'], 'm': ['m','M'], 'n': ['n','N'], 'o': ['o','O'],
    'p': ['p','P'], 'q': ['q','Q'], 'r': ['r','R'], 's': ['s','S'], 't': ['t','T'], 'u': ['u','U'], 'v': ['v','V'], 'w': ['w','W'],
    'x': ['x','X'], 'y': ['y','Y'], 'z': ['z','Z']}
    

sentence = str(input("Enter a sentence: "))
sentence_letters = split(sentence)

i = 0    
while i in range(len(sentence_letters)):
    actual_letter = sentence_letters[i]
    for key,value in letters():
        if value == actual_letter:
            print(actual_letter + ':' + str(sentence_letters.count(actual_letter)) + 'times')
            sentence_letters.remove(actual_letter)
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
```

This is the most recent message I get when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    for key,value in letters():
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, I am not even sure if this is the right way to solve this.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you have a `dict` variable, but you tried to make a function call with it.  Where are you confused?  I think you meant `letters.items()`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are other ideas that would be helpful here, just focusing on your error:

Looking at `letters()` - following an identifier by parentheses like this attempts to call it as you would a function. Because `letters` is not a function (or anything else that can be called) it can't be called. This is what the error is telling you.